# Is this grey piece a LEGO part?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, clone-brands

I have this piece in our box of random LEGO. It doesn’t have any studs to connect to so wonder if it’s even a LEGO piece.

Added a picture with other pieces for size perspective.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you take a picture of it next to a Lego 2x4 brick, or something of that nature to give us a better idea of the size?

Answer (score 11):

It is not LEGO but a clip for a Playmobil cannon.

https://www.libble.de/playmobil-7683/p/561335/

[image]

Comment: How the heck did you figure that out?  That's awesome :)

Comment: Exactly! I am amazed. I don’t know if we even have that cannon. I’m glad to remove it from the Lego box. :) Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This piece doesn't look like any actual Lego piece that I am familiar with. The way the back of it is designed it looks likely that it snaps onto something.  I'll throw a guess out here and suggest it possibly came off of a toy train or model train wheel assembly.  It looks vaguely similar to the outside section of Lego part# 2878 (Train Wheel RC Train, Holder).

[image]